# What's the best way to find DB connections left open in Java code?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-connection, prepared-statement

We have an enterprise Java project that uses an Oracle DB heavily, supports hundreds of concurrent users, and has been touched by dozens of developers over the last 10 years.  Every once in a while a developer forgets to  close either a Connection, PreparedStatement, or ResultSet object, and as the users use the system throughout the day, the open connections add up until Oracle throws a "Max Open Cursors" error.  We have increased the max open cursors value in the DB to what we feel comfortable with.

Is there software or maybe a technique for scanning thousands of lines of Java code and finding all the places where these DB objects are being left open?  We would want to run it once to find all the current places and then periodically to find any new ones.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use http://www.topcased.org/ (Eclipse/Java and other OpenSource tools) with many powerful and secure (Airbus testing mehtod) tools to found all pitfalls in a Critical system

Answer (score 3):

You could try running [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) over your sourcecode, that should pick up on any unclosed connections. There's a list of bugs it finds here:

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html

Look for the ones starting with ODR.

Comment: On netbeans you could use it as a plugin. Just select your project and click 'Source | Inspect...' and choose 'Findbugs' it should install it automatically if you haven't and will run the inspections. If you group by category on the inspector window you should find them on 'Bad practice | Method may fail to close database resource'

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are using any ConnectionPooling mechanism. If so,then the connection pool will be checking all the open connections. If you have implemented your own pool then you need to revisit the code to incorporate this check.

Answer (score 0):

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/index.html) has a couple of "bug patterns" for this:

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE
http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE_EXCEPTION_PATH

Answer (score 0):

[Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE) has been good at detecting connections that are not properly closed, as well as many other problems.

We use it as a maven plugin, which is invoked during the 'site' goal. Combined with a continuous integration tool (like Jenkins) this automates the process of detecting such potential problems.